# manifest.json properties are not recognizable when deployed

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vite, manifest.json

I have a solidjs project which I want to convert to a PWA. After building the project and deploying it, the browser cannot understand the properties of manifest.json. It throws the following errors
[image: manifest error]

I am attaching the manifest.json file and vite.config.js file contents

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Trading App",
    "short_name": "Trading App",
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#000",
    "theme_color": "#000",
    "scope": ".",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-48x48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-284x284.png",
            "sizes": "284x284",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/src/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        }
    ]
}
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import solidPlugin from "vite-plugin-solid";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin(), VitePWA({ registerType: "autoUpdate" })],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
  },
});
```

Any pointers will be really helpful. Thank you in advance